# Problemas de git para hacer un git reset --hard

Tags: git

Mi rama principal tiene un bug por lo cual deseo regresar a una rama anterior, como soy algo nuevo en git en mi búsqueda de información encontré que git reset  --hard es la ultima solución pero al usar este comando en mi gith bash se hace unicamente local(Pues si voy a mi github sigue la rama con el bug) y si trato de hacer un push me da error ya que me menciona que debo hacer un pull porque mi repositorio local esta desactualizado.

[Aca esta la imagen del error del git bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DZRk.png)

Comment: Ya que un `git --reset` reescribe la historia local (al hacer desaparecer commits que ya habían sido pusheados), un push normal será rechazado. Puedes añadir la opción `--force` al push. Si tu proyecto no obstante está compartido con otros desarrolladores, eso les causará problemas a los demás cuando intenten el `pull`, por la misma razón, y deberán hacer un `pull --force`. Se desaconseja reescribir la historia compartida por estas razones.

Comment: El proyecto tiene a varios desarrolladores trabajando en ello pero el problema fue que uno de mis compañeros hizo un push con un bug y ahora no se puede trabajar en el proyecto porque VS manda un error al cargar el proyecto entonces mi solucion era dar un git reset pero si conoces otra solución lo agradeceria

Comment: Bienvenid@ a SO.

Comment: Muchas gracias @eftshift0

Answer (score 1):

La forma en la que *deberías* resolverlo es *revirtiendo* la revisión en la que se produjo el daño y haciendo un pull request:

```
git checkout -b un-revert origin/main # asumiendo que la rama principal es origin/main
git revert el-id-de-la-revision-que-mete-el-bug
git push origin @ # enpujar la rama a origin
# entonces creas el PR y lo aceptas
```

Como dice @abulafia, reescribir la historia de una rama compartida (con un `git reset --hard` para hacer que retroceda en su historia) no es una buena idea. Es técnicamente posible, pero genera bastantes inconvenientes si los otros desarrolladores no están al tanto.... y para esto, procedo a explicar el caso.

Digamos que ya hiciste el `git reset --hard` y empujaste la rama y la pusiste en origin/main. En *mi* rama (yo soy otro de los desaarrolladores del equipo) en la que estoy trabajando, ya tengo el bug. Si hago mi trabajo y creo un pull request, en ese pull request se vería el bug... así que si lo aceptan, de nuevo aparece el bug en la rama origin/main. Para yo poder evitar que esto suceda, me toca hacer un trabajo adicional para evitar introducir el bug cuando haga el push / pull request:

```
git fetch origin # traer la posición actual de la ramas de origin
git rebase onto=origin/main vieja-revision-de-main-con-el-bug mi-rama # muevo las revisions de mi rama sin las del viejo main con el bug
# ahora si rama actual se montó sobre la _nueva_ posición de main que no tiene el bug
```

Ahora podría proceder a empujar la rama y crear el pull request sabiendo que el bug no se va a introducir. Como dije, es técnicamente posible hacer todo esto, pero requiere sincronización entre los miembros del equipo para estar al tanto de lo que está pasando con la reescritura de la historia de la rama compartida y también el conocimiento técnico para hacer el rebase que acabo de comentar de la forma apropiada.